# Is it possible to upload a bitmap into a texture without explicit conversion?

Tags: opengl

Is it possible to upload a bitmap (the data for `glBitmap`) into a texture *without* converting it into a pixel map myself? I didn't see `GL_BIT` for the parameter `type` in `glTexImage2D`.

Using the plain old `glBitmap` can be *quite slow*.

I know that converting a bitmap into a pixel map can be easily done within a couple of lines of code, but the **size of** the compiled **executable is critical**, so I'd better not invent the wheel if it's already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to upload a bitmap (the data for glBitmap) into a texture without converting it into a pixel map myself?

With current OpenGL functionality (of all versions): **No.**

You could however implement a fragment shader that interprets a GL_LUMINANCE8 or GL_R8 texture format as a bitmap. However you'll have to disable filterting (GL_NEAREST magnification and minification), and since you're going to have 8 bits per pixel you must do some reinterpretation of texture coordinates.

> Using the plain old glBitmap can be quite slow.

That is, because bitmap operations are usually not hardware accelerated.